# QGraphicsScene not responding to synthetic events

Tags: c++, events, qt

I have a very simple QGraphicsScene dervied class of my own:

```
class SceneComponent : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SceneComponent(QObject* parent = 0);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*);
};
```

And `mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)` is defined as:

```
void SceneComponent::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) {
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    std::cout<<"[Processing] MouseEvent"<<std::endl;
}
```

To display this QGraphicsView, this is as simple as:

```
QGraphicsView view(sceneComp);
view.show();
```

Now, when I click on the Window (for the QGraphicsView) that is displayed, I get the following output:

```
[Processing] MouseEvent
[Processing] MouseEvent
```

However, when I send a synthetic event using:

```
QMouseEvent* mevent = new QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPoint(50, 50),
            Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoModifier
);
QApplication::sendEvent(&view, mevent);
```

I get absolutely no output. Why is this?

On a related note, installing a `eventFilter` on the **QGraphicsScene** yields no results at all. This is probably (in my opinion) because of the fact that a **QGraphicsScene** expects a **QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent** instead of a **QMouseEvent**. This props up two questions:

1. Why is it so that a QGraphicsScene not accept standard QEvent and only QGraphicsSceneEvent?
2. Why is any QGraphicsSceneEvent derived class not instantiable?
3. Why is that I can send events to a QGraphicsScene using the sceneEvent method, but I need to specify a specific QGraphicsItem to send the event to?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for `QGraphicsSceneEvent`:

> When a QGraphicsView receives Qt
>   mouse, keyboard, and drag and drop
>   events (QMouseEvent, QKeyEvent,
>   QDragEvent, etc.), it translates them
>   into instances of QGraphicsSceneEvent
>   subclasses and forwards them to the
>   QGraphicsScene it displays. The scene
>   then forwards the events to the
>   relevant items.
>
> For example, when a QGraphicsView
>   receives a QMouseEvent of type
>   MousePress as a response to a user
>   click, the view sends a
>   QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent of type
>   GraphicsSceneMousePress to the
>   underlying QGraphicsScene through its
>   mousePressEvent() function. The
>   default
>   QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()
>   implementation determines which item
>   was clicked and forwards the event to
>   QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent().

1. `QGraphicsView` uses a viewport widget to display the contents of the scene and to receive user events. Try sending your event to the `QGraphicsView::viewport()` widget - it should work.
2. By design - see the quote, these events are probably not meant to be sent manually. `QMouseEvent` is associated with a physical action - ex. mouse click, while `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` is something abstract...
3. The question is not clear, but that quote might be helpful too. Which event in particular are you talking about? You should also keep in mind that `QGraphicsScene` has `QObject` level events, sent with `QApplication::sendEvent()`, and `QGraphicsItem` events, that are sent with `QGraphicsScene::sendEvent()`. These two kinds work in different planes and have different purposes. Refer to the docs for more info.